# Multiple css styles applied to one element, how to force one style over the other

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following css style:

```
.SkdTable tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #EDE7DD;
}
```

I also have this as well:

```
.SelectedSkd {
    background-color:#eedf36;
}
```

The latter will be applied on click event, so when a user clicks on a row I will be the selected row and shows different color:

```
var $selectedSkd;

function SelectedLine() {
    $(".SkdTable tbody tr").mousedown(function () {
        if ($selectedSkd!= null)
            $selectedSkd.removeClass("SelectedSkd");
        $(this).addClass("SelectedSkd");
        $selectedSkd= $(this);
    });
}
```

Now this works fine, except in even rows where I have set the `background-color` to be different, when adding the `SelectedSkd` style which has a different color, it doesn't show because the browser taking the first style as dominant. How to solve this?

Comment: Another option: http://jsfiddle.net/G8NTw/

Comment: @nnnnnn the `td` trick is smart one. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Note that of course it may not be suitable because if each row has several tds and they have borders or margins then the row highlighting would have "holes" in it. But I thought I'd throw the idea out there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use `!important` in css

like `.color {color:green !important;}`

but its better to call the parent name because a element called with parent has more value
for example

`a {color:green`}

but

```
div a {color:red}
```

will be implemented

Comment: However, `!important` should be used sparingly, avoid it if possible!